# How to find the position of an element within its parent container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Consider the following diagram:

[image]

I would like to calculate the vertical offset of the child element within its immediate parent. Note that the child element has a margin (indicated by the lighter blue).

jQuery provides [`.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/), but unfortunately the method calculates offset:

> "...relative to the offset parent."

The parent element in this case does *not* have `position` set to `relative` and unfortunately this cannot be changed.

In spite of this, is there any way to get the child element's offset relative to its immediate parent?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with

```
$(this).offset().top - $(this).parent().offset().top
```

Comment: I don't think that takes the parent's border into account, does it? If the parent element has an `8px` border, for example, the calculation above will result in an offset that is `8px` larger than it should be.

Comment: @NathanOsman: Unfortunately it does not. Assuming that the border is uniform you can compensate by subtracting `$parent.outerHeight() - $parent.height()`, but this does nothing for margins on the parent.

Comment: @NathanOsman Are you able to change the `CSS` of the parent or child? If you can, you could add `box-sizing: border-box;` and not have to worry about the border.